# Vue - nested child route causes reload parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuex, vue-router

I use vue and have problem with nested childs - it causes that parent component reloads data. Here is an example of my nested child route:

```
{
  path: '/products',
  name: 'products',
  component: MainLayout,
  redirect: {name: 'product-edit'},
  children: [
    {
      path: '/products/edit/:id',
      name: 'product-edit',
      component: ComponentProduct,
      redirect: {name: 'product-summary'},
      children: [
        {
          path: 'summary',
          name: 'product-summary',
          component: ComponentSummary
        },
        {
          path: 'description',
          name: 'product-description',
          component: ComponentDescription
        },
        {
          path: 'elements',
          name: 'product-elements',
          component: ComponentElements,
          children: [
            {
              path: ':element',
              name: 'product-elements-id',
              component: ComponentElementsId,
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**MainLayout**

It uses only `<router-view :key="$route.params.id"></router-view>` to display real element page.
I use such construction, to avoid issues with reloading after initial save. Example: /products/edit/0 -> user saves, gets response and is automatically redirected to /products/edit/12 (12 is new ID from API). Without that key, it doesn't work correctly because vue caches page with old data.

**ComponentProduct**

"Container" for sub-pages. This component loads product data (using id from params) push to vuex etc. It also includes `<router-view>`, but with `<keep-alive>` to avoid reloading already used tabs.

Summary and Description are simple sub-pages with some data.

**ComponentElements**

It's a special sub-page, that loads additional data (elements) for product and list them. It also uses vuex to get data. User can then click the element on a list to go to description into **ComponentElementsId**

But... it doesn't matter. On Summary or Description, it works fine, but if I visit ComponentElements, it causes that parent reloading data: page is not fully reloaded, route works fine, but why the parent is also refreshed? I do not touch id so it's strange for me.

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Comment: [This might answer your question](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/why-does-changing-nested-routes-reload-the-parent-route/46008)